# Sveltekit 1.0 CSS Button does not fill the whole parent

Tags: html, css, sveltekit

I am new working with HTML/CSS/JS and SvelteKit, so I'm struggling getting the look how I want it.

**HTML**

```
<h1>{market}</h1>

{#each articleList as item}

    <form action="" method="post">
        
        <p class="{item.checked ? "item-checked" : ""}">
            {item.quantity} {item.article} {item.place}
        </p>

        {#if item.checked}
            <button>DELETE</button>
        {/if}
        
    </form>
{/each}
```

**Global CSS**

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
    background: #3A3A3A;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    margin: 0 2em;
}
```

**Component CSS**

```
    form {
        border: 1px solid #57FF90;
        border-radius: 4px;
        margin-bottom: 1em;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
        width: 100%;
        height: 50px;
    }

    form p {
        color: #FFFFFF;
        font-size: 1.4rem;
        padding: 0 0.5em
    }

    .item-checked {
        text-decoration: line-through;
    }

    button {
        height: 50px;
        border: none;
        background-color: #57FF90;
        margin: 0;
        border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
```

As you can see on the screenshot, there is a [gap on the right side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvY8t.png).

I created a test HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
    
    <div class="wrapper">
        <form action="POST">
            <p>Random Text</p>
            <button>DELETE</button>
        </form>

        <form action="POST">
            <p>Random Text</p>
            <!-- <button>DELETE</button> -->
        </form>
    </div>

    <style>
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        .wrapper {
            padding: 1em;
        }

        form {
            background-color: red;
            margin-bottom: 1em;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            border-radius: 4px;
        }
        
        button {
            border: none;
            background-color: green;
            cursor: pointer;
            border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
        }

    </style>

</body>
</html>
```

Here everything is looking like expected. Why is there a difference?

Answer (score 0):

Your html test file isn't using the same CSS.  When I edit the styles in the test file to be the same as those you're using in the svelte code, I get a page that looks identical.

Also, I don't see the gap except at 175% zoom.  That's kind of odd, so I suspect that it's a rounding issue.  At any rate, it appears in the html test file as well as the served svelte file, so this isn't a Svelte or SvelteKit issue, as near as I can tell.